# Matching multiple data type constructors at once

Tags: haskell

Lets say we have this type declaration:

```
data D a = A a | B a | C a | D a | E a | F a
```

and want to define a function over it which divides the data constructors in 2 sets. It would be nice to write something like that:

```
g x | x `is` [A,B,C] = 1
    | x `is` [D,E,F] = 2
```

instead of matching on each constructor separately.

Is there any way to achieve this? I looked at uniplate but couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

If you often need to match for the same set of constructors, a helper function could be the simplest solution. For example:

```
getAbc :: D a -> Maybe a
getAbc (A v) = Just v
getAbc (B v) = Just v
getAbc (C v) = Just v
getAbc _     = Nothing
```

With such a helper function, the definition of `g` can be simplified like this:

```
g x = g_ (getAbc x)
  where
    g_ (Just v) = 1
    g_ Nothing  = 2
```

Or, using the [`maybe`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-Maybe.html#v%3Amaybe) function:

```
g = maybe 2 (\v -> 1) . getAbc
```

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution to me.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: If all constructors have the same type of fields, you could abuse Functor:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data D a = A a | B a | C a | D a | E a | F a
    deriving (Eq, Functor)

isCons :: (Eq (f Int), Functor f) => f a -> (Int -> f Int) -> Bool
isCons k s = fmap (const 42) k == s 42

is :: (Eq (f Int), Functor f) => f a -> [Int -> f Int] -> Bool
is k l = any (isCons k) l

g :: D a -> Int
g x | x `is` [A,B,C] = 1
    | x `is` [D,E,F] = 2
```

---

You could try

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data

data D a = A a | B a | C a | D a | E a | F a
        deriving (Typeable, Data)

g :: Data a => D a -> Int
g x | y `elem` ["A","B","C"] = 1
    | y `elem` ["D","E","F"] = 2
    where y = showConstr (toConstr x)
```

Comment: I found the same solution. The problem is with the String literals. It will be better if we can match against `[A,B,C]` as in the example I gave.

Comment: It's getting better, but what if I want it to work for constructors with different number fields?

Comment: @djv: Then `[A,B,C,D,E,F]` does not have a valid type.

Comment: Hm, yes you are right. But there should be some workaround. Maybe I'll have to use Template Haskell in the end.

Comment: @KennyTM: Probably it's possible to use tuple like `(a -> D a, (b -> b -> D b, ()))` (yesterday I saw that in LLVM bindings for indexing)

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to generalize answer of @KennyTM with:

```
data D a = A a | B a | C a a | D
    deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)

class AutoBind a where
    bindSome :: forall b . (a -> b) -> b

instance AutoBind Bool where bindSome f = f False
instance Num a => AutoBind a where bindSome f = f 0

class AutoConst a b | a -> b where {- bind until target type -}
    bindAll :: a -> b

instance AutoBind a => AutoConst (a -> b) b where bindAll = bindSome
instance (AutoBind a, AutoConst b c) => AutoConst (a -> b) c where bindAll = bindAll . bindSome

isCons :: (Eq (f a), AutoBind a, AutoConst b (f a), Functor f) => f a -> b -> Bool
isCons x y = fmap (bindSome const) x == bindAll y
```

But by some reason it doesn't work for constructor `C`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but how about this, using `Data.Data` and a "placeholder" type?

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data 

data X = X deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)
data D a = A a | B a | C a | D a a | E a a | F a a
    deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)


matchCons :: (Data a) => D a -> [D X] -> Bool
matchCons x ys = any ((== xc) . toConstr) ys
    where xc = toConstr x

g :: (Data a) => D a -> Int
g x | matchCons x [A X, B X, C X] = 1
    | matchCons x [D X X, E X X, F X X] = 2
```

Note that this avoids the issue of type signature/different constructor arity. There's probably a cleaner way to do something similar, as well.

Comment: You don't need `X`, just use `()` as a placeholder.

Comment: @djv: I wanted an explicit placeholder, to distinguish it from other types. But yes, `()` or almost anything else would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wish that Haskell patterns would have a way of specifying the "OR" of two patterns, similar to `|` in OCaml:

```
(* ocaml code *)
let g x = match x with
            A v | B v | C v -> 1
          | C v | D v | E v -> 2
```

Comment: What will be if `A`, `B` and `C` will have different types? How `1` can work with `v` if it matched with three different constructors? What will be if `C` will take two values? How `2` will know that there is another name for second value matched in `C` constructor in contrary to `D` where only `v` is available?

Comment: Well I put `v` in there just to show that you can get the value out of all three. But since `v` is not used, of course you could just do `A _ | B _ | C _` and it wouldn't matter if they had different types. And if `C` takes two values (in OCaml you can't take two values), you would just write `C _ _`. That way the type checker would be able to check that it is right.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. My solution would be to use a view, though personally I'd like something that's more canonically semantically equivalent (in some of the code I'm writing, laziness preservation is critical, so any extra unneeded pattern matches could render the technique unusable).

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

data D a = A a | B a | C a | D a | E a | F a
isABC (A v) = Just v
isABC (B v) = Just v
isABC (C v) = Just v
isABC _ = Nothing

f :: D Int -> Int
f (isABC -> Just v) = v
f (isABC -> Nothing) = 0
```